# Login com GORM com retorno intercalado entre ID e 0

Tags: mysql, golang, gorm

Galera, eu to aprendendo a programar na linguagem GO, e eu fiz uma api com um sisteminha de login.

```
func Authenticate(db *gorm.DB, auth models.UserAuthForm) uint {
    hasher.Write([]byte(auth.Password))
    pass_hash := hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
    user := models.User{}

    db.Select("id").Where("pass_hash = ? AND email = ?", pass_hash, auth.Email).First(&user)
    hasher.Reset()
    return user.ID
}
```

Essa função é chamada dentro de um controller com método POST no **login** é representado pelo Struct:

```
type UserAuthForm struct {
    Email    string `json:"email" form:"email" binding:"required"`
    Password string `json:"password" form:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

esse **uid** representa o id retornado e um cookie é salvo na Session

```
uid := crud.Authenticate(db, login)
if uid != 0 {
    sess := sessions.Default(c)
    sess.Set("user", crud.SaveCookieId(db, uid))
    sess.Save()
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"Message": "Success!"})
    return
}
c.JSON(401, gin.H{"Error": "Failed!"})
return
```

Meu real problema é que quando eu tento logar, primeiramento o retorno é:

```
{
    "Message": "Success!"
}
```

porém ao tentar denovo, retorna:

```
{
    "Error": "Failed!"
}
```

e se eu tento novamente, volta a a dar sucesso e assim manten-se intercalado